# How to insert a range of keys in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've just gone blank. I have a many to many relationship with three tables. Lets call them A, B and C. C stores the primary keys of the other two tables.

Now, I would like to insert all primary keys from table A, and lets say primary key 1 from B into table C. I just don't get it. All I came up with was some stored procedure that runs with a cursor through all primary keys of A and insert them with 1 into C. Guess, there is a much easier way to do this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT A_Id, 1
FROM A
```

where 1 is the single primary key from `B`.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for more info on the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? Or should 1 not be a constant but the result of a query from B?

Comment: That's strange. If I run the exact same statement on a test database, it works. We are talking about SQL Server here?